# t-sne perplexity for small data set

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction, perplexity

I am using [t-SNE](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) to visualize cytometry data. Most of guides I found (https://distill.pub/2016/misread-tsne/) warn how the choice of perplexity hyperparameter can influence the result.

However, **my data set size is really small, always expecting 10-30 points** since visualizing one point per cluster only. In this case, does a constant, reliable value of perplexity exist OR a mehod how to estimate it.

Comment: It's more about the data-statistics itself than the size. Go by your own eye!

Comment: I am stuck on the exact same problem. Small dataset size, getting different plots for different perplexities and learning rates..I know the data is separable because a linear classifier can separate the data, but if i pick the tsne with the lowest kl div, this does not give me any clusters. Some random values do. I am struggling to find a reliable method.